# Single Boot, Ubuntu 13.04 only, can not re-install with DVD

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, partitioning

I wanted to re-install 13.04, but when I insert the DVD it does not recognize it... and it just boots up as usual... it does not take me to the install DVD.  I put in a boot repair CD... and that is not recognized either.

I am very new to Linux... so I'm lost.

I wanted to re-install Ubuntu 13.04, because my boot is full, and only has 2.64 MB of storage left.  I cannot add or remove software, as they fail due to this error.  My intention was to re-install 13.04, use gpart to increase my boot drive space, to avoid this problem again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your DVD not booting is most likely due to the DVD-ROM not being the primary boot device in your BIOS. If you go into the BIOS menu (using F1 or F2 or DEL when you boot up. The exact key depends on your manufacturer)

Secondly the lack of space in your boot drive can be fixed by removing older kernels installed on your system and you dont necessarily need to do a full re-install. Check what kernels you have using:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

Then remove the older versions safely using:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-<older-version-numbers seen in the output of dpkg -l
```

**WARNING**

**Do not remove the latest version or your system won't boot obviously since you have any kernel installed.**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're unable to boot the installation DVD because your firmware is launching Ubuntu directly. (This is a little unclear because you've got too many instances of "it" in your first paragraph, making it hard to disentangle their intended referents.) If so, the solution is in your firmware. Chances are hitting a function key as the computer powers up will bring up a boot manager menu that will enable you to boot the DVD. Unfortunately, the details of what key to press vary from one computer to another. The time window for pressing the key is also likely to be quite narrow. Repeatedly pressing the key from the time you hit the power switch is the best way to get in on most computers.

That said, instead of re-installing, I recommend launching to the Ubuntu live CD/DVD and launching GParted. This will enable you to re-size your partitions, which should enable you to continue using your current setup. (You may need to deactivate swap space before you can move or resize that, and sometimes other, partitions.) That said, there's always a risk of data loss when re-sizing partitions, so be sure to back up any critical data before you begin.